# SingleEmailMessage - Test class - small coverage

Tags: apex, code-coverage, singleemailmessage

I wrote the EmailClass, and it works perfect, but I have a problem with Test Class. The coverage is only 27%. The Messaging.SingleEmailMessage and everything under it is not coverage. Could you please help me?

```
    public class EmailClass{
    @InvocableMethod
    public static void sendEmail() {

        
 //Contact and Case lists
    List<Contact> contacts =[Select Id From Contact where Email!=null];
    List<Case> cases = new List<Case>();
    cases = [Select Id,ContactEmail, Letter_Sent__c, Letter_Sent_Date__c, Reminder_Sent__c, Reminder_Sent_Date__c, Follow_up_Date__c, Responsibility_Center__c, Status, ContactId From Case Where Follow_Up_Date_in_Days__c=0 AND ContactEmail!=null AND subject='Periodic Service' AND account.company_code__c='US45' AND (status='Ready for Email' OR status='Waiting for customer') AND ContactId IN : contacts];
        
                  
 //ORG Wide Email Addresses lists   
        
    OrgWideEmailAddress AST = new OrgWideEmailAddress();
                AST = [SELECT Id, Address, DisplayName FROM OrgWideEmailAddress Where DisplayName='Austin']; 
        
    OrgWideEmailAddress ATL = new OrgWideEmailAddress();
                ATL = [SELECT Id, Address, DisplayName FROM OrgWideEmailAddress Where DisplayName='Atlanta'];

    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    for (Case cs : cases)
{
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    
    List<String> toAddress = new List<String>();
    toAddress.add(cs.ContactEmail);
    email.setToAddresses(toAddress);
    email.setWhatId(cs.Id);
    email.setTargetObjectId(cs.ContactId);
    email.setTemplateId('00X7Z0000027tioUAA');

     if (cs.Responsibility_Center__c =='AST' && cs.status=='Ready for Email')
    {
        cs.status = 'Waiting for Customer';
        cs.Letter_Sent__c = true;
        cs.Letter_Sent_Date__c = date.today();
        cs.Follow_up_Date__c = date.today().addDays(14);
        email.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(AST.id);
    }
    
    if (cs.Responsibility_Center__c =='ATL' && cs.status=='Ready for Email')
    {
        cs.status = 'Waiting for Customer';
        cs.Letter_Sent__c = true;
        cs.Letter_Sent_Date__c = date.today();
        cs.Follow_up_Date__c = date.today().addDays(14);
        email.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(ATL.id);
    }
 if (cs.Responsibility_Center__c =='AST' && cs.status=='Waiting for Customer' && cs.Letter_Sent__c == true && cs.Letter_Sent_Date__c != date.today())
    {
        cs.Follow_up_Date__c = date.today().addDays(14);
        cs.Reminder_Sent__c = true;
        cs.Reminder_Sent_Date__c = date.today();
        email.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(AST.id);
    }
    
    if (cs.Responsibility_Center__c =='ATL' && cs.status=='Waiting for Customer' && cs.Letter_Sent__c == true && cs.Letter_Sent_Date__c != date.today())
    {
        cs.Follow_up_Date__c = date.today().addDays(14);
        cs.Reminder_Sent__c = true;
        cs.Reminder_Sent_Date__c = date.today();
        email.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(ATL.id);
    }
 if (cs.Responsibility_Center__c =='AST' && cs.status=='Waiting for Customer' && cs.Letter_Sent__c == true && cs.Letter_Sent_Date__c != date.today())
    {
        cs.Follow_up_Date__c = date.today().addDays(14);
        cs.Reminder_Sent__c = true;
        cs.Reminder_Sent_Date__c = date.today();
        email.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(AST.id);
    }
    
    if (cs.Responsibility_Center__c =='ATL' && cs.status=='Waiting for Customer' && cs.Letter_Sent__c == true && cs.Letter_Sent_Date__c != date.today())
    {
        cs.Follow_up_Date__c = date.today().addDays(14);
        cs.Reminder_Sent__c = true;
        cs.Reminder_Sent_Date__c = date.today();
        email.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(ATL.id);
    }
```

My Test Class:

```
@isTest(seeAllData=true)
public class EmailClassTest {
   @isTest
    public static void sendEmail(){
            
        //Insert Profile
      Profile cus = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Customer Service'];   
         
        //Insert User
      User us = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='standarduser@testorg.com', 
            EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
            LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = cus.Id, CompanyName = 'E3',
            TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='standarduser@testorg.com'); 
        
        
        //Insert Account
      Account acct = new Account(Name='TestClassAccount', Customer_Segment__c = 'Hospitals', Calibration_Intervals__c = 'Half year');
      insert acct;
        
        
        //Insert Contact
      Contact con = new Contact(LastName='JasonSendEmail', email='sendemail@toatlanta.com', AccountId=acct.Id);
      insert con;
        
        
        //Insert Responsibility Center
      Responsibility_Center__c rc = new Responsibility_Center__c(Name='e3 AST');
        
        
        //Insert Case
       Case cas = new Case(Follow_up_Date__c = date.today(), Status = 'Ready for Email', ContactId=con.id, subject='Periodic Service', AccountId = acct.id,
                          Case_Reason__c = 'Business related', Reason = 'General Enquiry', Responsibility_Center_lookup__c=rc.id);
       insert cas; 

        
       //Insert Org-wide
       OrgWideEmailAddress[] addresses = [SELECT Id, Address, DisplayName FROM OrgWideEmailAddress Where DisplayName='Austin'];      
            
    
       Test.startTest();
       System.assertEquals(0, Limits.getEmailInvocations(), 'No emails should be sent');

       EmailClass.sendEmail();

       System.assertEquals(1, Limits.getEmailInvocations(), 'Emails should be sent');
       Test.stopTest();
        
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Cs.ContactEmail
```

Field is not populated in the Case of the test data that you've prepared, try populating that field in Testdata,should work